# TV show about a man investigating murders, starts seeing a woman that only he can see

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I have memory as a kid sitting down every weekend with my parents to watch a sci-fi programme on terrestrial TV, but I can't think of what it was called and neither can they.

One episode is about two guys, completely unrelated to each other, found dead on a street. The only thing they have in common is that both where carrying a business card with a web address on it. The guy who was investigating the murder typed the web address into his computer and it asked for his name. He put in his name and the screen went blank. With that, he begins to see a woman everywhere he goes, but only he can see her. The guy starts dreaming about having sex with this woman, only to wake up and find he is. The woman disappears and the guy starts getting sick. In the end the women turns out to be an alien and was killing men as they couldn't get her pregnant. Then the episodes ends.

The only other episode I remember is the investigators go into a room, and some alien butterflies attack them.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As opposed to extra-terrestrial TV ? :)  Seriously, what time frame we talking about (when were you a kid), that would be helpful.  American, Canadian, UK, other ?

Comment: Were the episodes unrelated as far as you can remember (e.g., Twilight Zone/Outer Limits) or were the investigators (or whomever) the main characters (e.g., X-Files)?

Comment: @Stan "Terrestrial tv" could refer to brodcast television or cable as opposed to satellite tv (in the same way that am/fm is refered to "terrestrial radio" by Sirus/X-M radio) Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the woman, and I know the timing is off, but the killer butterflies sounds like the "[Dreamscape](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/The_Dreamscape)" episode of Fringe that aired in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably [*Earth: Final Conflict*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth:_Final_Conflict). There is an episode with "killer butterflies" (they're really some machine that mimics things nearby in their environment).

Fast-foward to 2m45s to see them.

I am unable to find an episode that matches the description of your first example, but it is consistent with the general plot arc of the show (aliens, and a human detective who investigates such things).

Comment: Torchwood? The 'killer butterflies' were a type of giant alien mayfly.